# How can you tessellate degenerate triangles evenly?

Tags: opengl, glsl, tesselation

If you use the tessellation shader for triangle patches, you can only set the following four values to define the tessellation structure of the triangle:

```
gl_TessLevelOuter[0]
gl_TessLevelOuter[1]
gl_TessLevelOuter[2]
gl_TessLevelInner[0]
```

But if the original triangle patch is degenerated. For example, 2 edges are 2 units long, while the last edge is 0.5 units long. How can I tessellate it so that the generated triangles have almost the same edge length?

Well, the `gl_TessLevelOuter` values of the three edges can easily be set to values so that the length of the generated edges of the shorter and the longer edges are nearly equal. But the `gl_TessLevelInner` cannot be set to a simple value where the inner genated vertices match different outer tessellation levels. The outermost triangle ring is always mapped to the outer tessellation levels, and the inner generated vertices remain the same.

Are there any papers to fix something like this? Maybe directly in the render pipeline? Or through a compute shader? I'm only interested in **real time** algorithms.